# Dynamically grouping AND and OR sections of query

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this:

```
$query = "SELECT personaname, profileurl, avatarmedium, location, country, rank, rankurl, role, map, skype, teamspeak, microphone, esea, faceit, cevo, competitive FROM csgolistings WHERE active = 1";

if(isset($_POST['location']) && $_POST['location'] != "") {
  $location = $_POST['location'];
  $query .= " AND location = '$location'"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['country']) && $_POST['country'] != "") {
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $query .= " AND country = '$country'"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['rank']) && $_POST['rank'] != "") {
  $location = $_POST['rank'];
  $query .= " AND rank = '$rank'"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['competitive']) && $_POST['competitive'] != "") {
  $query .= " AND competitive = 1"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['cevo']) && $_POST['cevo'] != "") {
  $query .= " AND cevo = 1"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['faceit']) && $_POST['faceit'] != "") {
  $query .= " AND faceit = 1"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['esea']) && $_POST['esea'] != "") {
  $query .= " AND esea = 1"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['microphone']) && $_POST['microphone'] != "") {
  $query .= " AND microphone = 1"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['teamspeak']) && $_POST['teamspeak'] != "") {
  $query .= " AND teamspeak = 1"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['skype']) && $_POST['skype'] != "") {
  $query .= " AND skype = 1"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['role']) && $_POST['role'] != "") {
  $role = $_POST['role'];
  $query .= " AND role = '$role'"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['map']) && $_POST['map'] != "") {
  $map = $_POST['map'];
  $query .= " AND map = '$map'"; 
}
```

So I'd end up with `$query` being something like this (depending on what search filters were POSTed:

```
SELECT personaname, profileurl, avatarmedium, location, country, rank, rankurl, role, 
map, skype, teamspeak, microphone, esea, faceit, cevo, competitive FROM csgolistings WHERE active = 1 AND rank = '$rank' AND cevo = 1
```

My question is, how would I go about getting it to group the location and country as an AND, and then then the rest of the things being an OR? I would need to place brackets around the OR's so that it finds *all people from location AND country AND (cevo = 1, rank = '$rank')*. I could do that easily in a flat query but I'm dealing with $_POST data where some of it might not be posted. It depends on what the user requests.

Hope that makes sense.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: this is just an example, and you're really sanitising this input, right?

Comment: yea it's an example, im sanitising all the post data in my production code :)

Comment: okay so if location and country are set, they MUST be in the result, all the rest are optional?

Comment: @pala_ okay so basically this is a search filter. If none of the variables are set, it shows all rows. if country or location isset, then it needs to be used. for the rest of them though, i want to grab rows that contain any of the filters.

Comment: for the rest.. any or none? ie still match even if NONE of the or'd filters are set? or AT LEAST one of the filters?

Comment: @pala_ if one of them is set, match any with that thing set. I think that means I need AT LEAST one. If it contains at least one of the filters (apart from country and location) then show it. Note that country and location are separate. Someone may select a location but not a country.

Comment: no problem. done below. also i just realised how stupid my last question was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php
   $required = array ('location', 'country');
   $optional = array ('microphone', 'faceit', ... );

   $ands = array( '1' => '1');

   foreach($required as $req)
   {
      if(isset($_POST[$req]) && $_POST[$req] != '')
      {
        $ands[$req] = "$req = '{$_POST[$req]}'";
      }
   }

   $ors = array();

   foreach($optional as $req)
   {
      if(isset($_POST[$req]) && $_POST[$req] != '')
      {
        $ors[$req] = "$req = '{$_POST[$req]}'";
      }
   }

   $and_part = implode(" AND ", $ands);
   $or_part = empty($ors) ? "1" : implode(" OR ", $ors);

   $query = "select .... from ... WHERE $and_part AND ($or_part) ... ";
?>
```

You can easily extend the query then by adding your arguments to the appropriate arrays declared at the top, without having to add to a giant `if` chain.

given this `POST` input:

```
   $_POST = array(
     'location' => 'city',
     'country' => 'antarctica',
     'microphone' => 'loud',
     'faceit' => 'yes'
   );
```

`$query` will contain `select .... from ... WHERE 1 AND location = 'city' AND country = 'antarctica' AND (microphone = 'loud' OR faceit = 'yes') ...`

Comment: I agree with your approach. The 2nd `foreach` needs to concatenate `$or_part`, and you will need to conditionally set $or_part to '1' if it's an empty string, just before the final `$query=...` line.

Comment: Try using `implode()` instead of string concatenation. It's better for your health.

Comment: @pala_ thanks pala. I'm a bit of a PHP newbie. How would I modify this assuming that the value would be either a 1 or 0 for microphone, faceit, etc, but a text value for location, country, rank, and some others?

Comment: There should be no need for modification. MySQL is happy to let you insert '1' into an integer field and silently cast it to an int for you

Comment: @pala_ Oops, very stupid of me, was simply passing in the wrong value via post! Thank you so much for your help! Works perfectly. Learnt a lot from your answer too. Many thanks.

Comment: glad to help.  come back when you decide you need to be using prepared statements and bound parameters instead :)

Comment: I've generally been using Laravel but for this project decided to go back to a bit of spaghetti code haha... I was struggling getting some custom Facades and stuff to work. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's probably easiest when dealing with strings that need to be joined by delimiters (which can be anything from ", " to " AND ") to create an `array` to hold them, and then use the `join($delim, $array)` function to produce a new string with delimiters between each of the old strings. You can look at documentation for `join` in the PHP manual.

Second of all, my approach would be the following: try to get the country, and try to get the location. If they can't be gotten (because they aren't present in the POST), set the appropriate variable to null.

Then gather up all the rest of the strings into an array, say `$conditions`, leaving out the "AND" or "," or whatnot, because we'll conditionally add the appropriate one later. Here's an example:

```
if(isset($_POST['esea']) && $_POST['esea'] != "") {
    $conditions[] = "esea = 1"; 
}
```

Then: if there is a location and a country (i.e. both are set to non-null values), construct the query as such:

```
$query .= "location = '$location' AND country = '$country' AND (" . join(",", $conditions) . ")";
```

Otherwise, combine whatever location or country is with the $conditions joined by " AND ", like so:

```
if ($location) { 
    $conditions[] = "location = '$location'";
}
if ($country) {
    $conditions[] = "country = '$country'";
}
$query .= join(" AND ", $conditions);
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you wish to have your query like,

```
where active =1 and (location = '$location' and country = '$country') or (rank = '$rank' etc etc )
```

Well, if that's the case, You can simply put your location and country in series of `If and else IF statements`, like this

```
if((isset($_POST['location']) && $_POST['location'] != "") && (isset($_POST['country']) && $_POST['country'] != "") ) {
  $location = $_POST['location'];
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $query .= " AND (location = '$location' and country = '$country')"; 
}
else if(isset($_POST['country']) && $_POST['country'] != "") {
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $query .= " AND (country = '$country')"; 
}
else if(isset($_POST['location']) && $_POST['location'] != "")
{
   $location = $_POST['location'];
   $query .= " AND (location = '$location')"; 
}
```

And then you can keep contnuing with you normal contaenation with individual If joiing with OR

```
$query .= "OR ( ";
if(isset($_POST['rank']) && $_POST['rank'] != "") {
  $location = $_POST['rank'];
  $query .= " rank = '$rank'"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['competitive']) && $_POST['competitive'] != "") {
  $query .= " And competitive = 1"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['cevo']) && $_POST['cevo'] != "") {
  $query .= " AND cevo = 1"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['faceit']) && $_POST['faceit'] != "") {
  $query .= " AND faceit = 1"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['esea']) && $_POST['esea'] != "") {
  $query .= " AND esea = 1"; 
}

if(isset($_POST['microphone']) && $_POST['microphone'] != "") {
  $query .= " AND microphone = 1"; 
}

$query.= ")";
```

You know something of this kind. you do the combination as per you requirement. You can also use different variable for eacj "And" and "OR" part, then join them together. As per my suggestion this would would be better. Hope this helps.